# Inner workings of pytorch autograd.grad for inner derivatives

Tags: python, pytorch, autograd, automatic-differentiation

Consider the following code:

```
x = torch.tensor(2.0, requires_grad=True)

y = torch.square(x)
grad = autograd.grad(y, x)

x = x + grad[0]

y = torch.square(x)
grad2 = autograd.grad(y, x)
```

First, we have that `∇(x^2)=2x`. In my understanding, `grad2=∇((x + ∇(x^2))^2)=∇((x+2x)^2)=∇((3x)^2)=9∇x^2=18x` .  As expected, `grad=4.0=2x`, but `grad2=12.0=6x`, which I don't understand where it comes from. It feels as though the `3` comes from the expression I had, but it is not squared, and the `2` comes from the traditional derivative. Could somebody help me understand why this is happening? Furthermore, how far back does the computational graph that stores the gradients go?

Specifically, I am coming from a meta learning perspective, where one is interested in computing a quantity of the following form `∇ L(theta - alpha * ∇ L(theta))=(1 + ∇^2 L(theta)) ∇L(theta - alpha * ∇ L(theta)` (here the derivative is with respect to `theta`). Therefore, the computation, let's call it `A`, includes a second derivative. Computation is quite different than the following `∇_{theta - alpha ∇ L(theta)}L(\theta - alpha * ∇ L(theta))=∇_beta L(beta)`, which I will call `B`.

Hopefully, it is clear how the snippet I had is related to what I described in the second paragraph. My overall question is: under what circumstances does pytorch realize computation `A` vs computation `B` when using `autograd.grad`? I'd appreciate any explanation that goes into *technical* details about how this particular case is handled by `autograd`.

PD. The original code I was following made me wonder this is [here](https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/blob/master/examples/rl/maml_trpo.py); in particular, lines 69 through 106, and subsequently line 193, which is when they use `autograd.grad`. For the code is even more unclear because they do a lot of `model.clone()` and so on.

If the question is unclear in any way, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a few changes:

1. I am not sure what `torch.rand(2.0)` is supposed to do. According to the text I simply set it to 2.
2. An intermediate variable `z` is added so that we can compute gradient w.r.t. to the original variable. Yours is overwritten.
3. Set `create_graph=True` to compute higher order gradients. See https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.autograd.grad.html

```py
import torch
from torch import autograd

x = torch.ones(1, requires_grad=True)*2

y = torch.square(x)
grad = autograd.grad(y, x, create_graph=True)
z = x + grad[0]

y = torch.square(z)
grad2 = autograd.grad(y, x)
# yours is more like autograd.grad(y, z)

print(x)
print(grad)
print(grad2)
```

Comment: Yes, 1. was my mistake. Thanks. Do you know why in my case ```grad2=12.0```?

Comment: @Schach21 Yours is like `autograd.grad(y, z)`. `z=6` so `grad2=12.0`.